# Dual representation of problems involving $f$-divergences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis, duality

Studying some problems arising in decision-making under model uncertainty, I'm led to consider the following problems.

Let $\mathbb E_P$ and $\mathbb V_P$ denote the expectation and variance operators w.r.t the probability measure $P$. Let $P_0$ be a fixed probability measure.

**Question 1:** How to rewrite the problem
$$\sup_{P \ll P_0}\mathbb E_P[Z]+\mathbb V_{P_0}(dP/dP_0),
$$
as a 1D optimization problem $\min_{c \in \mathbb R}J(c,P_0)$ involving the reference measure $P_0$ ?

**Question 2:** In general, given a convex function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(z) \ge \varphi(1)=\varphi'(1) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb R$ and $\varphi(z) = +\infty$ for $z < 0$, how to rewrite the problem

$$\sup_{P \ll P_0}\mathbb E_P[Z]+\mathbb E_{P_0}[\varphi(dP/dP_0)],
$$
as a 1D optimization problem $\min_{c \in \mathbb R}J(c,P_0;\varphi)$ involving the reference measure $P_0$ and the potential $\varphi$?

**Observation:** I the sought-for representation should be obtainable via the envelope theorem, but I'm not sure how to get it.